# convert string from multiple languages to POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

```
s <- c("25avr2014","25okt2014","25mar2014")
```

In a string containing dates from different languages (with different month abbreviations) - how can I convert this string to POSIXct format considering the month abbreviations are from different locales?

In case someone else needs it - sure code can be improved, but works for me:

```
library(readr)
library(data.table)
parsedate <- function(df=s,list_countries){
  t2 <- lapply(list_countries,function(x){
    temp<- locale(x,asciify=T)
temp$date_names$mon_ab <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", temp$date_names$mon_ab)
parse_date(df,format = "%d%b%Y",locale = temp)
  })
names(t2) <- list_countries
t2 <- data.table::rbindlist(list(t2))
t2[,':=' (uni=apply(.SD,1,function(x) uniqueN(x,na.rm=TRUE)),
         val=apply(.SD,1,function(x) unique(x[!is.na(x)] ))
         )]
if (all(t2$uni==1)) {cat("Parsing OK\n")}
    else cat("Beware - Parsing problem\n")
t2[,val]
}

>  parsedate(s,c("fr","en","de"))

Parsing OK
[1] "2014-04-25" "2014-10-25" "2014-03-25"
```

Comment: Use a dict and convert to one language first?

Comment: cycle among/try a bunch of different locales and merge non-NA values?